# "LIKE" or "=" Operator not using index seek

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, clustered-index

got the following query

```
SELECT * FROM myDB.dbo.myTable 
WHERE name = 'Stockholm'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM myDB.dbo.myTable 
WHERE name LIKE('Stockholm')
```

I have created a fulltext index which will be taken when I use `CONTAINS(name,'Stockholm')` but in the two cases above it performs only a clustered index scan. This is way to slow, above 1 second. I'm a little confused because I only want to search for perfect matches which should be as fast as `CONTAINS()`, shouldn't it? I've read that `LIKE` should use a index seek at least, if you don't use wildcards respectively not using wildcards at the beginning of the word you're searching for. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have a non-fulltext index defined on that column? Because a fulltext index will only be used (so far as I'm aware) specifically for queries that use fulltext predicates (like `CONTAINS`)

Comment: DO you have an index on the Name column? A Full-Text index has nothing to do with table indexes and is not for equality of LIKE queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet you have no indexes on the name column. A Full-Text index is NOT a database index and is NOT used, unless you use a full-text predicate like CONTAINS.

Comment: You bet it right. I don't mention that fulltext-index isn't used for LIKE. It's quite confusing because some People write simply about indexes and don't distinguish between them. So in my table was no "non-fulltext" index on the name column. I created one and it is pretty fast now. Thanks, i will post a complete solution later. (not enough reputation so far)

Comment: Actually, when people say 'index' they never mean 'full-text index', not just for SQL Server but for almost any RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Panagiotis Kanavos and @Damien_The_Unbeliever there was no "non-fulltext" index on my name column. I had to simply add a index with the following query:

```
CREATE INDEX my_index_name
ON myDB.dbo.myTable (name)
```

This improves the performance from slightly above one second to under a half second.